# How to set the options of a selectbox in horizontal direction HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

So if the question is unclear, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwYXn.png) a sketch of what I want. I couldn't find a similar question regarding this matter so that's why I'm asking.

I want it to be as simple as possible and css-only.

```
<div class="myselectbox">My Selectbox
  <select class="myselect_class" id="myselect_id">
    <option>OPT1</option>
    <option>OPT2</option>
    <option>OPT3</option>
    <option>OPT4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's not how `select` works think of it as dropdown.

Comment: you cannot .. you have to create it by yourself

Comment: Instead of native `select`, use `ul li` structure to mimic `select` and style it like whatever you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of a html "select"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Comment: @comments. Thanks for the clarification and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to put in your display settings under css. As the default display is of block section.
so the CSS code change you need to do is as follow:

```
.myselect_class{
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 260px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1float;}
.dropdown-content a {float: left;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: inline;
 
}
a{
float: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
  <div>
   <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

you can't do it with `<select>`, you need to do like a custom dropdown

Comment: Is it really not possible to do it with `select`? You're example is not bad, but I want the options to be displayed directly on the side of the selectbox.